# how to convert type of variables in python?

Tags: python

Suppose

```
    type(a) = <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

now I have another variable `b` (maybe a `<type 'list'>`), I want to convert it into the same type of `a`. How to do this? For example,

```
    >>> type(a)
    <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
    >>> b = [[[100, 200, 300]]]
    >>> type(b)
    <type 'list'>
```

Now, I want to

```
    >>> type(b)
    <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

I want to do this in a python script. I don't know in advance what is the type of `a`. I just take `numpy.ndarray` as an example.

**UPDATE:**

In fact, in the python script, it receive some strings from `sys.argv`. And then it will assign these strings into some predefined variables in this script. These predefined variables may be `int`, `list`, `numpy.ndarray`, or else. For `int` or `list`, this can be done by `from ast import literal_eval; MyDict[sys.argv[1]] = literal_eval(sys.argv[2])`. But if `MyDict[sys.argv[1]]` is a `numpy.ndarray`, the `literal_eval` cann't reassign the list `[[[100, 200, 300]]]` into a `numpy.ndarray`. So I'm seeking a more effective way to do this.

Comment: Reassign that variable to be that type?

Comment: @Mr.goosberry, yes!

Comment: @Mr.goosberry, I want to do this in a python script. I don't know in advance what type of the `a` is. I just take `numpy.ndarray` as an example.

Comment: There's not a general way to do this, and there shouldn't be. What if `a` is an int and `b` is a list. How would you convert `b` to the type of `a`. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @MorganThrapp, yes, so we can add some `try ... catch ...` in the script. But if `a` and `b` could be compatible, then we just reassign the type of `b`.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a `list` into a python array, use [`numpy.asarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html).
For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a = np.asarray(a)
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> type(a)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

More generally, how to convert the type depends on what conversion you want.
To convert to a string use [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#textseq), to convert to an integer use `int`, and so on.
Note that in python the variables to not have a fixed "type", so you can simply reassign a variable to convert its type. For example

```
>>> a = '2' # we can start from a string..
>>> a = int(a) # and than get an int
>>> a
2
>>> a = [1, 2, 3] # we can now completely change and make *a* a list
>>> a = tuple(a) # or maybe you want a tuple?
>>> a
(1, 2, 3)
```

To check if a variable is of a certain type you can use `isinstance`, so to convert the type of `b` depending on the type of `a` you can do something like

```
def conditional_conversion(a, b):
    if isinstance(a, int):
        b = int(b)
    elif isinstance(a, str):
        b = str(b)
    elif isinstance(a, list):
        b = list(b)
    return b

>>> a = 12
>>> b = '51'
>>> b = conditional_conversion(a, b)
51
```

Of course, you'd need to consider the various possibilities that you could incur into.
Also, this type of conversion will likely throw exception if `b` cannot be converted into the type of `a`, so a try-catch construct will probably be beneficial.

Comment: Thank you. But maybe `a` is another type. I just take `numpy.ndarray` as an example.

Comment: @mining Python has many ways to convert from different data types. Pick one for your specfic case, and use it.

Comment: @Mr.goosberry, yes, but the `a` may be another types, e.g., `list`, `dict`, etc. And also `b` may be another types, not just a `list` type.

Comment: Yes, I know this kind of conversion. I want to reassign the type of one variable according to that of another variable.

Comment: @mining but do you know what `b`'s type will be?

Comment: @Mr.goosberry, it may be a `int`, `list`, `numpy.ndarray` or else. Maybe we can write a `if ... elif ... elif ...`. So I post this question just for a effiective and simpler answer.

Comment: thanks, this is a solution, but I'm not familiar with python, so I post this question for a simpler and more effective answer.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you don't *just* want to convert the type; you also want to preserve the existing value.  (Otherwise you could just assign `b` to an empty object of the new type and be done with it.)

Very generally, you would call the new type's constructor, passing in the old value.  For example, if you have an integer and you want to covert it to a string, call `str()` on the integer value:

```
a = 5        # type(a) is <type 'int'>
a = str(a)   # type(a) is now <type 'str'>
```

Or to convert a string to a list:

```
a = "hello"  # type(a) is <type 'str'>
a = list(a)  # type(a) is now <type 'list'>
```

However this method is *very* generic and won't be usable in a lot of cases.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer. In fact, in the python script, it receive some strings from `sys.argv`. And then it will assign these strings into some predefined variables in this script. These predefined variables may be `int`, `list`, or `numpy.ndarray`. For `int` or `list`, this can be done by `from ast import literal_eval; MyDict[sys.argv[1]] = literal_eval(sys.argv[2])`. But if `MyDict[sys.argv[1]]` is `numpy.ndarray`, the `literal_eval` cann't reassign the list `[[[100, 200, 300]]]` into a `numpy.ndarray`.

Comment: If your question was about converting specifically from `list` to `numpy.ndarray`, then you should have asked that specific question.  You asked for a _general_ solution, and I gave one, with the caveat that it won't work in many cases.

Comment: Thanks, John. Sorry for unclear description. I know the conversion from `list` to `numpy.ndarray`.  Yes, I post this question for a more effective way to achieve this goal, not many `if else`.